# PostgreSQL deadlock detected

Tags: postgresql, relational-database, database-deadlocks

Assume I've table A with 20 million entries, and another smaller table B with <1 million entries.

I'm trying to add a FK from B pointing to A.

```
Process 1240: ALTER TABLE "product" ADD CONSTRAINT 
"product_top_id_56635_fk_tableb_id" FOREIGN KEY ("top_id")
REFERENCES "tableb" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Does this alteration change anything on tableb? If not why is it causing a deadlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the foreign key won't modify A, but it will lock rows in A. This is to guarantee that those values cannot be modified or deleted while the constraint is created.

So there can be deadlocks with other transactions that lock rows in both tables.

Avoid modifications to A, either with an explicit lock or by waiting for a maintenance window.

Comment: But why does B care about the modifications of A, is there a FK type that doesn't check the integrity and thus doesn't have to lock A?

Comment: A foreign key is an integrity constraint, so it will always check integrity. That's its job. If you don't want integrity checked, don't define a foreign key. The constraint has to prevent modifications of A that would render the constraint invalid, like removing rows on which row in B depend.